# How do I extract ASCII data from binary file with unknown format, in Windows?

Tags: windows, binary, ascii

On Windows, what is the best way to convert a binary file where the internal structure is unknown less that its contents are ASCII in nature back to plain text?

Ideally the conversion would produce a "human"-readable version.  I think the file should contain something like the following:

```
Date: 10 FEB 2010
House: 345 Dogwood Drive
Exterior: Brick
```

Comment: Explain "convert". Do you want a a lossless transformation that can be undone? Do you want to extract some kind of description that's human readable?

Comment: The way you edited your question looks like you want that program to effectively reverse-engineer the format. I'm pretty sure that's not reasonable at the time being, unless you restrict yourself to a very small subset of all binary data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Linux/Unix:

```
$ strings < unknown.dat > ascii-from-unknown.txt
```

This is of course not so much a "conversion" as a straight up extraction, by just filtering out the non-ASCII bytes. It's useful quite often, though.

In general, without more knowledge of the file's internal format, I don't think you can do much better.

Comment: I plus'd you up, because forgetting to add the Windows OS was my mistake.   Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: There are Windows versions of strings as well.  For example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

Comment: And all strings does it look for 'N' adjacent printable characters so it isn't too difficult to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, a [hex dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) might fit the bill: It's a pure ASCII format that represents the entire file without any loss of data (but being quite wasteful with space).

It is **not** really human readable, but since you don't explain why you want to do that, it's the best I can offer.

There are [several simple tools](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+hex+dump) that produce a hex dump on Windows.